# Repository for Spring MVC Class design

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, dao, dto

I have a question at design level. There is an argument between using DAO or DTO in our application.

I have gone through the existing posts and got to know that DTO is used only when representing complex objects. However, my view can be generated using just a join operation on my tables.

Database:

Tables:

```
game
game_details (has a primary key of Game) - There will be at max 4 rows for a given game_id
```

My view contains all the columns from tables game and game_details. And each of those 4 rows will be displayed in different tabs. 
For every change in the view, there is 3/4 probability of updating both tables.

Now what is the best approach.
1. Wrap entire view as a DTO.
2. Or define my mode Game with a list of GameDetails Model object.

If we go with second approach, will there be any change in how we persist the data.

Comment: It's not an argument of either/or: DAO and DTO are fundamentally different things. The answer about granularity depends on where you'd save the data, who else might have access to it, and what you choose to do about "dirty reads".  Since a Game can have many users, there might be changes from others as you cycle between tabs.  I'd recommend creating a separate REST service for data access.  Let the UI be something independent from the service.

Comment: First of all DTO cannot be opposed to DAO, because they play in different (and independent) parts of your application. DTO connects you application to outside world. When `DAO` connects application to DB. Probably you wanted to ask `DAO` vs `Repository`? Or `Repository `vs `Aggregate`?

Comment: Understood. I will correct that. My question if rephrased, is using a DTO best approach or just use Repository to aggregate my tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Access Object's do just that. How they do it depends on the technology you are using; I like Hibernate for CRUD operations.

I use the term Data Transfer Object's to refer to the objects that describe my API. So, I will define DTO's that match my JSON passed in my RESTful services.

I use DTO's *and* entity objects to decouple my API from my database. It involves more processing, but I've found the extra effort to be worthwhile.

How you define your DTO's is up to you and stems from how you describe the data passed in your service API's. A flat structure is simpler to populate using JDBC; however, it generally contains a lot of redundant data and requires more logic to process. A structured approach, where header contains a list of detail, *may* require a bit more work to populate, but it avoids redundancy and is easier to consume.